# How to fix overfull \hbox automatically?

Tags: matrices, overfull, automatic

the problem is "Overfull \hbox (39.27608pt too wide) detected at line 357", the code of the first image is this, where the problem apear:

```
\[\begin{array}{cl}
    = & (x-\delta_{n+1})\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \\
                    & & & \gamma_{n-1} & \delta_{n-1} - x & \gamma_{n} \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n} & \delta_{n} - x
                   \end{array}  \right| - \\
    - & \gamma_{n+1}^2 \left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \\
                    & & & \gamma_n & \delta_n - x & \gamma_{n+1} \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n+1} & \delta_{n+1} - x
                   \end{array}  \right| \\
```

[image]
and the code of the error solved by hand, is this:

```
\[\begin{array}{cl}
    = & (x-\delta_{n+1})\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \\
                    & & & \gamma_{n-1} & \delta_{n-1} - x & \gamma_{n} \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n} & \delta_{n} - x
                   \end{array}  \right| -  \gamma_{n+1}^2 \left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \\
                    & & & \gamma_n & \delta_n - x & \gamma_{n+1} \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n+1} & \delta_{n+1} - x
                   \end{array}  \right| \\
    = &  (x-\delta_{n+1})\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \\
                    & & & \gamma_{n-1} & \delta_{n-1} - x & \gamma_{n} \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n} & \delta_{n} - x
                   \end{array}  \right| + \gamma_{n+1}^2 \left|\begin{array}{ccccccc}
                    \delta_1 - x & \gamma_2 & & & & & \\
                    \gamma_2 & \delta_2 - x & \gamma_3 & & & & \\
                    & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & & \\
                    & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & & \\
                    & & & \gamma_n & \delta_n - x & \gamma_{n+1} & \\
                    & & & & \gamma_{n+1} & \delta_{n+1} - x & 1 \\
                    & & & & & 1 & 0
                   \end{array}  \right| \\
\end{array}\]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Automaton is unable to read and understand your math formulae, so it is unable to decide how to create better format of your formulae. May be neural networks? But this is not the case of TeX, 40 year old program. You must decide yourself what to do with your formulae.

Comment: I don't know if I am being able to explain myself well.
What I want is to write the addition/subtraction of two matrices without the need to use a line separator of the type ``` - \\ & - ``` or as you wrote it ``` \\[\jot] &\ qquad\quad - ```.
Since if I do it in a single line with a font size of 10pt I have no problems, but if I increase the size I get off the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you require by an "automatic way". I would strongly recommend that you employ the machinery of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package -- specifically, the package's environments for multi-line math material -- and replace the nested `array` environments with (a) an `align*` environment in place of the "outer" `array` structure and (b) `vmatrix` environments in place of `\left| \begin{array}{...} ... \end{array}\right|`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'vmatrix' environments, 
                     % and for '\allowdisplaybreaks' macro

\begin{document}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begingroup % limit scope of next instruction to current TeX group
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25} % default value: 1.0
\begin{align*}
 (x-&\delta_{n+1})p_n(x) - \gamma_{n+1}^2p_{n-1}(x) \\
    &= (x-\delta_{n+1})\det(J_n-xId) - \gamma_{n+1}^2\det(J_{n+1}-xId) \\
    &= (x-\delta_{n+1})
       \begin{vmatrix}
            \delta_1{-}x & \gamma_2 \\
            \gamma_2 & \delta_2{-}x & \gamma_3 \\
            & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & & \gamma_{n-1} & \delta_{n-1}{-}x & \gamma_{n} \\
            & & & & \gamma_{n} & \delta_{n}{-}x
       \end{vmatrix} \\[\jot]
    &\qquad\quad -\gamma_{n+1}^2 
       \begin{vmatrix}
            \delta_1{-}x & \gamma_2 \\
            \gamma_2 & \delta_2{-}x & \gamma_3 \\
            & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & & \gamma_n & \delta_n{-}x & \gamma_{n+1} \\
            & & & & \gamma_{n+1} & \delta_{n+1}{-}x
       \end{vmatrix} \\[2\jot]
    &= (x-\delta_{n+1})
       \begin{vmatrix}
            \delta_1{-}x & \gamma_2 \\
            \gamma_2 & \delta_2{-}x & \gamma_3 \\
            & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & & \gamma_{n-1} & \delta_{n-1}{-}x & \gamma_{n} \\
            & & & & \gamma_{n} & \delta_{n}{-}x
       \end{vmatrix} \\[\jot]
    &\qquad\quad +\gamma_{n+1}^2 
       \begin{vmatrix}
            \delta_1{-}x & \gamma_2 \\
            \gamma_2 & \delta_2{-}x & \gamma_3 \\
            & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
            & & & \gamma_n & \delta_n{-}x & \gamma_{n+1} \\
            & & & & \gamma_{n+1} & \delta_{n+1}{-}x & 1 \\
            & & & & & 1 & 0
       \end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if I am being able to explain myself well.
What I want is to write the addition/subtraction of two matrices without the need to use a line separator of the type
 ``` - \\ & - ``` 
or as you wrote it ``` \\[\jot] &\ qquad\quad - ```.
Since if I do it in a single line with a font size of 10pt I have no problems, but if I increase the size I get off the sheet.